# EJB client not displayed on Weblogic

Tags: java, ejb

Hi I have created an EJB 3.0  App and have exposed this EJB as a webservice . Have created locale and remote interface for the same.

Now the port of the server 7005 where I have deployed this EJB is blocked whereas through SSH a proxy 17005 is opened .

Now when I go to the weblogic console and open the EJB and go to the client using port 17005 I could see the WSDL of my service but not able to see the EJB client .

Also when I use this WSDL through Soap UI i am able to run the application whereas when I create a remote client of this EJB I am getting "javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://10.129.196.209:17005" error

My EJB remote looks like

```
 @Remote
public interface AnalyticNotificationWebservice {
// public String executeAndSave( ) throws Exception;

/**
 * Method description
 * 
 * 
 * @param input
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void sendNotification(AnalyticsReportsSchedulerDTO 
    analyticsReportsSchedulerDTO) throws Exception;



 }
```

whereas my Bean code is like

```
@Stateless(name = "AnalyticsNotificationEJBWebservices", mappedName = "Trellis-
  AnalyticsNotificationEJBWebservices")
        @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
        @WebService(name = "AnalyticNotificationEJBWebserviceBean", 
    serviceName =     "AnalyticNotificationEJBWebserviceBean", 
    targetNamespace =  
   "http://xmlns.ac/cps/scheduler/quartz-scheduler/ebm", 
   portName = "AnalyticNotificationServiceBeanServicePort")    
    public class AnalyticNotificationEJBWebserviceBean implements
        AnalyticNotificationWebservice,
   AnalyticNotificationWebserviceLocal {

    @Override @WebMethod @Oneway
    public void sendNotification(
            AnalyticsReportsSchedulerDTO 
   analyticsReportsSchedulerDTO)
            throws Exception{
.......
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "SSH proxy is opened". Should you be connecting with t3s instead of t3?

Comment: Basically I have blocked the port 7005 and through ssh command I have opened port 17005 to connect.                                            ssh -fN oracle@<<ipaddress>> -L <<ipaddress>>:17005:<<ipaddress>>7005